# How can I know the data type of field after handling by plugin in fluentd

Tags: fluentd

I am using td-agent (td-agent 1.4.2).I use parser filter to output logs to elasticsearch.I want to know what data types of some field before they are sent to elasticsearch.

Comment: <system>
    log_level trace
</system>

Comment: place it in /etc/td-agent/td-agent.conf. you can see the data type.string,number and so on